# distance between histograms

Tags: machine-learning, probability-theory, statistics

I have 2 histograms that represent the height of characters in 2 images. 
example:

- 1 ******
- 2 **********
- 3 ************
- .
- .
- .
- 100 **************

For these 2 histograms I compute the peaks. And To **check** if these 2 images are **similar** I compute the interseciton between the indices of the 2 images.
Example:
For image 1 the indices of the peaks are 1, 10 and 13
for image 2 the indices of the peals are 1,10, 14.
Image1 Inter Image1 = 2 So these images are similar.

But I feel that the intersection is not enough. I think that i should also use the size of the buckets of the histograms peaks.

Is there  a way to use to both of them to measure the similarity in **1 function** So that I can have a stable similarity function?

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=histogram+distance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you normalize your histograms you then have an empirical pmf. There are numerous methods to calculate distances of pmfs, such as [Kullback-Leibler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) and [Jensen-Shannon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%E2%80%93Shannon_divergence) divergences. If the base-set of the histograms are exactly the same then KL divergence will work fine. If they intersect, but are not exactly the same, then JS divergence will work instead.

Be careful as KL divergence is non-symmetric. That is, given two pmfs $P$ and $Q$, $\text{D}_{\text{KL}}(P||Q)$ may not be equal to $\text{D}_{\text{KL}}(Q||P)$. On the other hand $\text{D}_{\text{JS}}$ is symmetric, but still not a metric.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be the following algorithm:

1. Normalize the histograms h1 and h2, so that both have an area of the same (scalar) size (i.e. the integral of the peak height over all peaks should be the same to compensate for different sample sizes). You receive normalized histograms h1n and h2n.
2. Overlay both normalized histograms h1n and h2n and calculate the intersection for every single peak. You should receive a new histogram that represents a two-dimensional intersection (h3).
3. Integrate the peak height of the new intersection histogram h3.

In summary, you receive a single scalar value that represents the normalized intersection area.

This algorithm requires that h1 and h2 have the same number of peaks.

Answer (score 0):

This [article](https://mpatacchiola.github.io/blog/2016/11/12/the-simplest-classifier-histogram-intersection.html) provides a simple and efficient solution to your problem.
Basically, it calculates the overlap between the two histograms and then normalizes it by second histogram (you can use first).
You can use this function to calculate the similarity between the histograms.

```
def return_intersection(hist_1, hist_2):
    minima = np.minimum(hist_1, hist_2)
    intersection = np.true_divide(np.sum(minima), np.sum(hist_2))
    return intersection
```